# Thread joblist management

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, concurrency

I'm working in C#.

I have been searching for ages now, and can't seem to find anything that fits my situation. This is an abstract of my real problem since it's too complicated for me to explain.

I have a worker thread that prints integers from a list with a small delay after each print, when the integer is printed, it's deleted from the list, when the list is empty it should wait for more to be added.
Now i need to be able to - at any point - add a number of my choosing to the front of this list. But i'm getting concurrency issues. Because they obviously can't work on the list at the same time. I have been looking at the producer-consumer model but i can't get it to fit this project.

Do you know of any examples that fit this situation?

Comment: would the singleton pattern suit?

Comment: won't help with the concurrency, i need to lock the list and unlock it after print, but i don't know how to get it to work properly.

Comment: are you looking for ConcurrentList<T>?

Comment: Something like that, but more on how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about these solution:

```
class Example
{
    private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _hasNewData;
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<int> _queue;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _stopConsumers;
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _waitForStopping;
    private Task _printTask;

    public Example()
    {
        _hasNewData = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
        _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
        _stopConsumers = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _waitForStopping = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        _printTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PrintMethod());
    }
    public void Add(int v)
    {
        _hasNewData.Set();
        _queue.Enqueue(v);
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        _stopConsumers.Cancel();
        _waitForStopping.WaitOne();
    }
    private void PrintMethod()
    {
        while (!_stopConsumers.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _hasNewData.Wait();
            int v;
            while(_queue.TryDequeue(out v))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dequed: {0}", v);
            }
        }
        _waitForStopping.Set();
    }
}
```

Use in this way:

```
Example e = new Example();
e.Start();
int k = 0;
while (true)
{
    e.Add(k++);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: That example just seems to count one int, then wait for input, and then repeat. But it needs to be counting on and on and at a random point i input my integer, and it then prints that input through the printer thread.
1, 2, 3, 4, 1337, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 - 1337 being my integer.

Comment: Dear, BoinQ. It isn't clear for me what do you need. Could you try to explain in other way or give more details?

Comment: I can see it's very close.
I have a list of integers, this list needs to be shared with a thread that reads the whole list integer by integer. And a thread where i can input new integers to the front of this list. So putting my "job" before the other "jobs" in the list.

So the background thread is just a slave that prints and deletes the first integer in the list until it's empty. And when it's empty it waits for more integers to print.

Comment: In my example, as you can see, I'm using ConcurrentQueue (FIFO). One can add new ints by calling Example.Add(). PrintMethod is waiting for input and when there is any input, it begins read all items from the queue.

Comment: This worked brilliantly after a little editing, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This worked brilliantly.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] ints = new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110,120,130,140,150 };
        Example e = new Example();
        e.AddRange(ints);
        e.Start();
        int k = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            e.Add(input);

        }
    }
}

class Example
{
    private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _hasNewData;
    private readonly ConcurrentStack<int> _queue;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _stopConsumers;
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _waitForStopping;
    private Task _printTask;

    public Example()
    {
        _hasNewData = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
        _queue = new ConcurrentStack<int>();
        _stopConsumers = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _waitForStopping = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        _printTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PrintMethod());
    }
    public void AddRange(int[] ints)
    {
        _hasNewData.Set();
        _queue.PushRange(ints);
    }
    public void Add(int v)
    {
        _hasNewData.Set();
        _queue.Push(v);
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        _stopConsumers.Cancel();
        _waitForStopping.WaitOne();
    }
    private void PrintMethod()
    {
        while (!_stopConsumers.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _hasNewData.Wait();
            int v;
            while (_queue.TryPop(out v))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dequed: {0}", v);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
        _waitForStopping.Set();
    }
}
```